# Loop response result onto HTML List

Tags: javascript, node.js

My goal is to take everything inside of placeResult and load it onto a list. Your list would be like below

photos, formatted_address, rating

photos, formatted_address, rating

photos, formatted_address, rating

Where on each `<li>` there is a new photo from the array, a new address and ratings from the array response. Example placeResult response here:

```
{formatted_address: "1111 Example Rd, CityName, State 33333, USA", name: "Ruby Tuesday", photos: Array(10), rating: 4.1},
{formatted_address: "2222 Example Rd, CityName, State 44444, USA", name: "McDonalds", photos: Array(10), rating: 3.1},
{formatted_address: "3333 Example Rd, CityName, State 55555, USA", name: "Burger King", photos: Array(10), rating: 2.1}
```

My best guess is I need a secondary loop to handle this. Currently its just giving me a repeat of the same photo from the same location and fills the `<li>`.

**Code**

```
if (placeResult.photos) {
    const ulList = document.createElement('ul');
    infoPane.append(ulList);
    const liList = document.createElement('li');
    ulList.append(liList);
    for (var i = 0; i < placeResult.name.length; i++) {
      console.log("PlaceResult", placeResult.formatted_address);
      const firstPhoto = placeResult.photos[0];
      const photo = document.createElement('img'); 
      photo.classList.add('hero');
      photo.src = firstPhoto.getUrl()
      liList.appendChild(photo);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably should rewrite 8 line:

```
const firstPhoto = placeResult[i].photos[0];
```

or you made a mistake in loop exit condition, maybe you mean:

```
for (var i = 0; i < placeResult.length; i++) { .. } //iterate over places array
//or..
for (var i = 0; i < placeResult.photos.length; i++) { .. } // iterate over photos array
```